# Code not compiling - ends up in xmemory

Tags: c++, vector

I just got started trying to learn how to code graphics using C++. When compiling a linear interpolation code, the code does not run and sends VC++ to the xmemory file. No errors or warnings given, thus leaving me with nothing to work on. What did I do wrong? I suspect the problem is connected to the way I assign the vectors, yet none of my changes have worked.

Here is the code:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "SDLauxiliary.h"

using namespace std;
using glm::vec3;
using std::vector;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
SDL_Surface* screen;

void Draw();

void Interpolate( float a, float b, vector<float>& result ) {

    int i = 0;
    for ( float x=a;x < b+1; ++x )
    {
        result[i] = x;
        i = i + 1;
    }

}

void InterpolateVec( vec3 a, vec3 b, vector<vec3>& resultvec ) {
    int i = 0;    
    for (int add=0; add < 4; ++add) {
        float count1 = (b[add]-a[add])/resultvec.size() + a[add];
        float count2 = (b[add]-a[add])/resultvec.size() + a[add];
        float count3 = (b[add]-a[add])/resultvec.size() + a[add];

        resultvec[i].x = (count1, count2, count3);
        resultvec[i].y = (count1, count2, count3);
        resultvec[i].z = (count1, count2, count3);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    vector<float> result(10); // Create a vector width 10 floats
    Interpolate(5, 14, result); // Fill it with interpolated values
    for( int i=0; i < result.size(); ++i )
        cout << result[i] << " "; // Print the result to the terminal

    vector<vec3> resultvec( 4 );
    vec3 a(1,4,9.2);
    vec3 b(4,1,9.8);
    InterpolateVec( a, b, resultvec );
    for( int i=0; i<resultvec.size(); ++i )
    {
        cout << "( "
        << resultvec[i].x << ", "
        << resultvec[i].y << ", "
        << resultvec[i].z << " ) ";
    }

    screen = InitializeSDL( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    while( NoQuitMessageSDL() )
    {
        Draw();
    }
    SDL_SaveBMP( screen, "screenshot.bmp" );

    return 0;
}

void Draw()
{

    for( int y=0; y<SCREEN_HEIGHT; ++y )
    {

        for( int x=0; x<SCREEN_WIDTH; ++x )
        {
            vec3 color(1,0,1);
            PutPixelSDL( screen, x, y, color );
        }
    }

    if( SDL_MUSTLOCK(screen) )
        SDL_UnlockSurface(screen);

    SDL_UpdateRect( screen, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Remove as much code as you can and still have the error.

Comment: Ah yes! I misunderstood the assignment of vectors. I changed the assignments in InterpolateVec and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I can not post a comment to the question so I'll write my thoughts as answer.

```
    resultvec[i].x = (count1, count2, count3);
    resultvec[i].y = (count1, count2, count3);
    resultvec[i].z = (count1, count2, count3);
```

It looks like you (or one of your library) overload `operator,` for `float` to make `vec2` and after `vec3`. Nice solution, but if I right, then no reason to assign each components to that value and your code will be similiar to:

```
    resultvec[i] = (count1, count2, count3);
```

Again this is just a hypothesis! I can not compile your code and see the error.

Also I am not understand why you using `i`, which equal to `add`.

Comment: Interesting that you didn't stumble across this code. In Python, `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple. In C++, it is the comma-operator chaining the values 1, 2 and 3 and a pair of brackets around it. The comma operator evaluates the operands and returns the value of the last, so `(1, 2, 3)` is the same as `3`.

Comment: in that context evaluation of count1 and count2 seems senselessly, so I think that there is operator overloading somewhere in including code. If I'm right then the overloaded function returns something (possibly) different from the float and an error occurs when assigned.

Comment: yep. It is possible in C++. I think there is defined `vec2 operator,(float f1, float f2)` and `vec3 operator(vec2 f2, float f3)`.
So with c++11 variadic templates posible to create tuple. To be honest I just now came up with the idea, but as it turns out everything is already done. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). But there is not written about the comma operator override.

Comment: Possible, yes. Advisable, probably not. Actually roughly 30% of all cases where I saw that operator in action were bugs, like e.g. some misaligned brackets or so. That's the reason for my surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that some of you could not compile the code; it may be that you have not installed the libraries (the n00b speculating, yay ...).

So here is what I did to make it work (less code is better in this case, as the first comment stated):

```
void InterpolateVec( vec3 a, vec3 b, vector<vec3>& resultvec ) {
resultvec[0].x = a[0];
resultvec[0].y = a[1];
resultvec[0].z = a[2];

float count1 = (b[0]-a[0])/(resultvec.size() - 1);
float count2 = (b[1]-a[1])/(resultvec.size() - 1);
float count3 = (b[2]-a[2])/(resultvec.size() - 1);

for (int add=1; add < 5; ++add) {
    a[0] = a[0] + count1; 
    a[1] = a[1] + count2; 
    a[2] = a[2] + count3; 
    resultvec[add].x = a[0];
    resultvec[add].y = a[1];
    resultvec[add].z = a[2];
}
 }
```

I discovered (after many an hour ...) was that I did not need to add count1, count2 and count3; vec3 is such a type that adding count1 does what I wanted it to; assigning color (i.e. something like (0,0,1)). Am I making since? My vocabulary is not that technical I know.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could save some time and let `glm::vec3` do what `glm::vec3` is supposed to do.

In the mean time; here, have a cookie (*cookie.png*)

```
void Interpolate(vec3 a, vec3 b, vector<vec3>& result) {  
    vec3 diffStep = (b-a) * (1.0f / (result.size() - 1)); // Operator overloading
    result[0] = vec3(a);                                   
    for(int i = 1; i < result.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = result[i-1] + diffStep;
    }

}
```